# Angular2 unit test + creating object of an interface

Tags: unit-testing, angular

Little exhausted here, may be that is why my title is not so accurate.

I am writing a unit test for my `DummyService`:

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class DummyService {

        getAllDataSources():Promise<Array<DummyData>> {
            return new Promise<DummyData[]>(resolve =>
                setTimeout(()=>resolve([]), 1000) // 1 seconds
            );
        }
    }
```

Please assume am returning a list of `DummyData` objects from `getAllDataSources`.

Now, I have a structure/interface for the dummy data in the same service file:

```
 export interface DummyData{
            Name:string;
            IsActive:boolean;
        }
```

I tried to write unit test for this service:

```
import {DummyService, DummyData} from './dummy.service';
import {
    beforeEachProviders
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {provide} from '@angular/core';

export function main() {

    describe('dummy.service', () => {
        let dsService:DummyService;

        it('should fetch data', ()=> {
           dummyData: DummyData = new DummyData(); // >>>> culprit...
           expect(1).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
}
```

This unit test seem little funny, as I am really not calling `DummyService`s function to get the list of `DummyData`.

I am doing this because I was getting some issue, due to which I was not able to see my test. I did some research, spent a whole day and finally found that this structure `DummyData` is the CULPRIT. I proved this to myself when I tried creating an object of it in my unit test (*in the code above*) and I got the following error:

```
FAILED TESTS:
  dummy.service
    ✖ should fetch data
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)
      Chrome 50.0.2661 (Linux 0.0.0)
    ReferenceError: **DummyData is not defined**
        at eval (/home/aodev/WebstormProjects/Data Federation App/data-mapping-app/dist/dev/app/shared/datasource.service.spec.js:8:28)
        at Object.eval (/home/aodev/WebstormProjects/Data Federation App/data-mapping-app/node_modules/@angular/core/testing/testing.js:80:25)
```

So, can someone tell me please, what am I doing wrong?
Why I cannot create the object of `DummyData` inside my unit test?

Please help!

Comment: Maybe a missing import for `DummyData` in your `DummyService` file.

Comment: From the code above, it looks like `DummyData` is an interface and not a class. Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Because they are not classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript interfaces exist only during compile time, runtime knows nothing about interfaces.

This is how you create instance that implements interface:

```
interface itest
{
    success:boolean;
}

let a:itest = {success: true}; //compiler checks that object matches interface itest
```